# What is the application server for an asp.core application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webserver, application-server

In the world of dotnet especially asp.net core who plays the role of the web application server ? if we said that IIS is the web server who is the web application server then ?
Another word, Did MS provide a specific name to refer to application server like IIS refers to a web sever.
**This what I know, we need an application server that receives http requests coming from web server IIS that coming from client , therefor the application server take the http request an generate dynamic contents then pass it to the web server (IIS) who will return the result to the client**

Comment: No, the asp.net core applications run as self host; also you can deploy your application in server like IIS but this is not required, you can read more on  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you said self-hosted ? because what I know is we need an application server that receives http requests coming from web server IIS  that coming from client , therefor the application server take the http request an generate dynamic contents then pass it to the web server (iis) who will return the result to the client

Comment: Some materials here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows